# Sum convergence test (arctan involved)

Tags: convergence-divergence

I need to help with this problem:

Find out if this sum is convergent or not.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (arctan(n+1)-arctan(n))$

Thank's for help! :)

Comment: Arctan(a) - Arctan(b) = Arctan[(a-b)/(1+ab)] could help

Comment: Before you do anything else write down a couple of partial sums. Say up to 6 and 7. Stare at them long and hard...

Comment: Telescope ... !

Answer (score 3):

The partial sum S(k) = arctan(k+1) - arctan(1) ---> pi/2 - pi/4 = pi/4 as k --> infinity.